# How to make has_two relationship in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `employee` model and `address` model. Now employee can have two addresses one is **permanent** and other is **temporary**.

I want the relationship that employee has two addresses one is permanent and other is temporary.

Also how can I save address for the employee in employee's controller while creating employee?

Comment: People should read about the "zero one infinity" rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule It explains why it makes sense to have has_one and has_many, but there will never be a has_two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the relationship that employee has two addresses one is
>   permanent and other is temporary.

You can use 2 `has_one` :

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employee
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :permanent, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'permanent_address_id'
  has_one :temporary, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'temporary_address_id'
end
```

Read the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

> how can I save address for the employee in employee's controller while
>   creating employee?

This can be achieved with [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: So `permanent_address_id` & `temporary_address_id` will be integer rows in address table?

Comment: This sounds very strange to have columns permanent_address_id and temporary_address_id in address table and they actually containing employee id.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:-

```
has_one :permanent_address, class_name: 'Address', :foreign_key => 'permanent_address_id'
has_one :temporary_address, class_name: 'Address', :foreign_key => 'temporary_address_id'
```